# Angular2 Component Styling by ID

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, styling

I am using `kendo-ui` controls for Angular and need a way to style individual components. I know you can do stuff like `:host /deep/ .k-numeric-wrap {}` to apply styling to all of the components of same class, but how would I apply the `:host /deep/` strategy to individual components?

For example `kendo-autocomplete` looks like this:

[image: kendo-control]

I defined that `kendo-autocomplete` as `#language` id in the HTML. Does anyone know of a way to access the styling just for `#language`? I've tried:

```
:host #language .k-autocomplete {}
:host(#language) .k-autocomplete {}
```

Comment: `:host /deep/  #language .k-numeric-wrap {}` ?

Comment: @n00dl3 I've tried that, no luck

Comment: What style are you trying to set?

Comment: @Shai I posted an answer with a way I got it to work...

Comment: Where are you placing this styling? In which file?

Comment: I've updated my answer and included a demo

Comment: @Shai Thanks! I should've tried that combo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `id="language"` on the `kendo-autocomplete` element.

That's the reason why a selector with `#language` in it isn't working.

Also, since the `k-autocomplete` class is on the element itself, the selector should be `#language.k-autocomplete`, without a space between them. Anyway, the class part of the selector is redundant since an ID selector is the most specific.

**EDIT:**

OK this should work (tested):

1. Use `id="language"` instead of `#language`.
2. In your styling, write the following:

   ```
   /deep/ #language {
       max-width: 10em;
   }
   ```

See demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TktmngsAxig87arr1cUZ?p=preview).

Comment: I do have it declared in my HTML: ` <kendo-autocomplete #language formControlName="langSelect"></kendo-autocomplete>`

Comment: Replace it with `<kendo-autocomplete id="language" formControlName="langSelect"></kendo-autocomplete>`

Comment: Ok - and try what I did before? Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean the CSS selectors? Yeah, try the ones you tried before, should work now.

Comment: I tried them all, none worked unfortunately. Isn't IDing with `#` the appropriate way to reference templated elements in Angular?

Comment: I've worked with angularJS and Angular2/4 and haven't seen this kind of IDing. I've also tested IDing this way a bit and it doesn't seem to work... Did you try using `/deep/` with `id="language"`?

Comment: I did. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I've found to work so far is the old inline `style` tag. This is not the best solution but works for my case since I only want to set the `max-width`:

```
<kendo-autocomplete #language
    style="max-width: 10em;"
    formControlName="langSelect"
    [valueField]="'Descrip'"
    [placeholder]="'e.g. French'"
    [data]="langSet">
</kendo-autocomplete>
```